# Will it help to set NVARCHAR(15) column as index if it's used in WHERE LIKE clause?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, indexing

I'm setting up a SQL Server (t-Sql) table that contains a column that's defined as `NVARCHAR(15)` that may be selected in a `WHERE` clause using `LIKE` statement, as such:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [table] 
WHERE [Name] LIKE @SearchName 
  AND [other] = @something 
  AND [etc] AND [etc]
```

`@SearchName` - may contain wildcards specified by an end-user

The question I have, will it help to define my `Name` column as a nonclustered index?

PS. This table may contain millions of records, and it can be updated [1-10] thousands of times a day. So I'm trying to minimize the number of indexes in this table that may not be necessary.

Comment: @MitchWheat: It may return hundreds and even thousands of records per `select` query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how many rows would be returned. If the Name column contained more than (approx.) only 10% different values then because you are doing a `SELECT *` an index on `[Name]` probably wouldn't be used.

If the selectively of `[Name]` is higher and the rows aren't very wide, then Yes an index would be beneficial.

Just noticed the bit about wildcards..If it's only a wildcard suffix then an index might be used.

You would be better off creating an index that contains all the WHERE filter columns in the order of most selectivity.

Ultimately, why not create the index and monitor it's usage. SQL Server 2005 onwards has some built in reports for doing this. You can find these reports by starting SQL Server Management Studio and right-clicking a database name. From the menu that appears, click the Standard Reports, and then select the Index Usage report.

You can also do this directly in TSQL:

```
SELECT  
    OBJECT_NAME(dm.[object_id], dm.database_id) AS [object_name],
    dm.index_id,
    dm.user_seeks,
    dm.user_scans,
    dm.user_lookups,
    dm.user_seeks + dm.user_scans + dm.user_lookups AS user_reads,
    dm.user_updates AS user_writes ,
    dm.last_user_scan,
    dm.last_user_update
FROM    
    sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats dm
WHERE
    dm.database_id > 4    -- filter out system databases
    AND OBJECTPROPERTY(dm.OBJECT_ID, 'IsUserTable') = 1
    AND dm.index_id > 0  -- filter out heaps 
ORDER BY 
    dm.user_scans DESC
```

Comment: Thanks. What's the tool to determine index usage?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm afraid it will not help. First of all, because you have wildcards in queries and query `like '%searchtext%'` is very very heavy. Secon - amount of data and frequency of updates.
I advice you to create [full-text index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317(v=sql.120).aspx) and use [full-text search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE CONTAINS(Name, '"chain*" OR "full*"')
```

This will be much faster and you can also use wildcards.

Comment: As much as I love SQL Server, it's full text search really sucks. Avoid if you can.

Comment: @MitchWheat of couse, full-text search problem should be solved with special engines (ElasticSearch or others), but if you have (or if you need) MSSQL only it can be solved too, maybe with less quality of search. But we don't know all requirements

Comment: Regardless of requirements: avoid SQL Server's full text search. It's rubbish compared to other (free) solutions.